# Lightweight File Manager for use in a Windows Preinstallation Environment

Tags: windows-pe, explorer

I need a free (preferabally open source) lightweight file manager for Windows that can run in a stripped down *Windows Preinstallation Environment*. It doesn't matter if it is text-based or GUI but must run in Windows PE.

As a side note, someone should create the tag: `file-manager`

Comment: Given what this site is for, file-manager would be a better tag on SuperUser, if it's not there already.

Comment: Why the close votes? This deals with Windows Preinstallation environment, I think it's relevant to this site.

Comment: I agree that this question is appropriate for this site, I was just commenting that the tag would be much more common on SU.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: This is really a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) -- the best we can give you is a list of things, and Google will always be a more up-to-date list than anything we post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freecommander is what you are looking for. Its free and lighter than TC. http://www.freecommander.com

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), which is Shareware. Supporting every major version of Windows, plus Android, it presents a side-by-side view of files and folders. There doesn't seem to be any pictures on the main site, but you can find a range [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=890&q=total+commander&gbv=2&oq=total+commander&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1412l3323l0l3875l15l13l0l4l4l0l180l1145l0.9l9l0&surl=1).